# How to bind to specific collection item?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How to bind let's say `TextBox.Text` to `myDictionary["testElement"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried removing the quotes around `testElement`? If the key is a string that should work.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx):

> Indexers of a property can be specified within square brackets following the property name where the indexer is applied. For instance, the clause Path=ShoppingCart[0] sets the binding to the index that corresponds to how your property's internal indexing handles the literal string "0". Multiple indexers are also supported.
>
> [...]
>
> Inside indexers you can have multiple indexer parameters separated by commas (,). The type of each parameter can be specified with parentheses. For example, you can have Path="[(sys:Int32)42,(sys:Int32)24]", where sys is mapped to the System namespace.

Comment: Wow! that works. I was a bit surprised. And what if key isn't string. What if it's enum?

Comment: Works with enums as key, tested that.

Comment: Thank you! First I tried enums with fully qualified value like 'myEnum.val1' or 'local:myEnum.val1' and failed but now I see that I have to use just 'val1'.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a derived from IValueConvertor class. You bind to the dictionary itself, and set the ConverterParameter='testElement', in your converter you get both the dictionary and the key and return what's needed.